# Reading Bengali with python Natural Language Toolkit

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I want to read Bengali texts in NLTK's CategorizedPlainCorpusReader. For this Snapshot of my Bengali text file in gedit text editor:

[image]

Snapshot of file in sublime text editor:

[image]

From the snapshots you can see the problem. The problem is Unicode composition problem (the dotted ring is a dead giveaway). And here is the code segment for reading texts:

```
>>> path = os.path.expanduser('~/nltk_data/corpora/Bangla')
>>> from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
>>> from nltk import RegexpTokenizer
>>> word_tokenize = RegexpTokenizer("[\w']+")
>>> reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(path,r'.*\.txt',cat_pattern=r'(.*)_.*',word_tokenizer=word_tokenize)
>>> reader.sents(categories='pos')
```

The output is:

[image]

The output should be 'একবার' rather than 'একব' 'র'. What can be done?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `RegexpTokenizer("[\u0980-\u09FF']+")` (not sure if you also need the `u` prefix here).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: Added as an answer with the link to the reference Web site with the Bengali Unicode character range.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide the Unicode range for [Bengali characters](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0980-09FF).

Use

```
word_tokenize = RegexpTokenizer("[\u0980-\u09FF']+")
```

The apostrophe can remain in the character class as is.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from nltk.corpus.reader import CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk import RegexpTokenizer

path = os.path.expanduser('~/nltk_data/corpora/Bangla')    
word_tokenize = RegexpTokenizer("[\u0980-\u09FF']+")
reader = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(path, r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(.*)_.*', word_tokenizer=word_tokenize)
reader.sents(categories='pos')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the question, of which the accepted answer is appropriate, instead I will fill in the missing pieces, i.e. why the regex pattern in the question failed.

The failure point was:

```py
word_tokenize = RegexpTokenizer("[\w']+")
```

The suggested alternative in the accepted answer was:

```py
word_tokenize = RegexpTokenizer("[\u0980-\u09FF']+")
```

But why didn't `[\w']+` work? The Python documentation provides the following description of `\w`:

> For Unicode (`str`) patterns:
> Matches Unicode word characters; this includes alphanumeric characters (as defined by `str.isalnum()`) as well as the underscore (`_`). If the `ASCII` flag is used, only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is matched.

The crux is that it *does not* match Unicode word characters as defined by Unicode.

The Unicode definition of `\w` is `[\p{alpha}\p{gc=Mark}\p{digit}\p{gc=Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]`.

Python `re` modules implementation includes digits, most alphabetic characters, and one *connecter punctuation*. It does not include most *connecter punctuation*, and does not include any mark or join controls. This will impact, many African languages, both written in Latin script, and in other scripts. It will impact some Arabic script languages, most South Asian languages, and many South east Asian languages.

To illustrate with Bengali:

```py
import re
text = "সমস্ত মানুষ স্বাধীনভাবে সমান মর্যাদা এবং অধিকার নিয়ে জন্মগ্রহণ করে। তাঁদের বিবেক এবং বুদ্ধি আছে; সুতরাং সকলেরই একে অপরের প্রতি ভ্রাতৃত্বসুলভ মনোভাব নিয়ে আচরণ করা উচিত।"
word_pattern = r'\w+'
print(re.findall(word_pattern, text))
# ['সমস', 'ত', 'ম', 'ন', 'ষ', 'স', 'ব', 'ধ', 'নভ', 'ব', 'সম', 'ন', 'মর', 'য', 'দ', 'এব', 'অধ', 'ক', 'র', 'ন', 'য',
# 'জন', 'মগ', 'রহণ', 'কর', 'ত', 'দ', 'র', 'ব', 'ব', 'ক', 'এব', 'ব', 'দ', 'ধ', 'আছ', 'স', 'তর', 'সকল', 'রই', 'এক',
# 'অপর', 'র', 'প', 'রত', 'ভ', 'র', 'ত', 'ত', 'বস', 'লভ', 'মন', 'ভ', 'ব', 'ন', 'য', 'আচরণ', 'কর', 'উচ', 'ত']
```

If we use codepoint ranges as indicated in the accepted answer:

```py
codepoint_pattern = r'[\u0980-\u09FF]+'
print(re.findall(codepoint_pattern, text))
# ['সমস্ত', 'মানুষ', 'স্বাধীনভাবে', 'সমান', 'মর্যাদা', 'এবং', 'অধিকার', 'নিয়ে', 'জন্মগ্রহণ', 'করে', 'তাঁদের', 'বিবেক', 'এবং', 'বুদ্ধি', 
# 'আছে', 'সুতরাং', 'সকলেরই', 'একে', 'অপরের', 'প্রতি', 'ভ্রাতৃত্বসুলভ', 'মনোভাব', 'নিয়ে', 'আচরণ', 'করা', 'উচিত']
```

If we change the regular expression engine we are using, results differ:

```py
import regex
print(regex.findall(word_pattern, text))
# ['সমস্ত', 'মানুষ', 'স্বাধীনভাবে', 'সমান', 'মর্যাদা', 'এবং', 'অধিকার', 'নিয়ে', 'জন্মগ্রহণ', 'করে', 'তাঁদের', 'বিবেক', 'এবং', 'বুদ্ধি',
# 'আছে', 'সুতরাং', 'সকলেরই', 'একে', 'অপরের', 'প্রতি', 'ভ্রাতৃত্বসুলভ', 'মনোভাব', 'নিয়ে', 'আচরণ', 'করা', 'উচিত']

script_pattern = r'[\p{Bengali}]+'
print(regex.findall(script_pattern, text))
# ['সমস্ত', 'মানুষ', 'স্বাধীনভাবে', 'সমান', 'মর্যাদা', 'এবং', 'অধিকার', 'নিয়ে', 'জন্মগ্রহণ', 'করে', 'তাঁদের', 'বিবেক', 'এবং', 'বুদ্ধি',
# 'আছে', 'সুতরাং', 'সকলেরই', 'একে', 'অপরের', 'প্রতি', 'ভ্রাতৃত্বসুলভ', 'মনোভাব', 'নিয়ে', 'আচরণ', 'করা', 'উচিত']
```

Results using `[\w]+` in the `re` and `regex` modules will differ. `[\p{Bengali}]+` can be written as `[\p{Script=Bengali}]+` or `[\p{sc=Bengali}]+`.

`\p{Bengali}` resolves to `[\u0980-\u0983\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BC-\u09C4\u09C7\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CE\u09D7\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E3\u09E6-\u09FE]`.

There is also the *script extension* `\p{scx=Bengali}` which resolves to `[\u0980-\u0983\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BC-\u09C4\u09C7\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CE\u09D7\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E3\u09F0-\u09FE\u1CF7]` adding the *avagraha* to the repertoire of Bengali characters.